# Particle system is showing weird behavior when I instantiate the GameObject on which the particle system component is already attached

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, particles, particle-system

Another noob question. I am making an TPP game. when I instantiate GameObjects (more than 1) (which have a predefined ParticleSystem component on them -: with simulation space set to world, collisions module enabled and the type of collision is set to 3d and send messages checkbox is also ticked and enable dynamic box collider check box is also ticked with life loss set to 1) during runtime...When the enemies(gameobjects which i instantiated) get close to the player(the main player), they stop emmiting the particles, but when they are far away they do emit particles. I tried many thing but nothing is working. Please help :-)

[Here the instantiated gameobjects are close to the player but are not emitting any particles](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aayx0.png)
[This is my collision module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rC3G9.png)